# To combine nested conditions

Tags: google-sheets

1. AND(AND($GD3>$C$2;$GD3<=$C$3);(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)))
2. AND(AND($GD3>=$D$2;$GD3<=$D$3);(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)))
3. AND(AND($GD3>=$E$2;$GD3<=$E$3);(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)))
4. AND(AND($GD3>=$F$2;$GD3<=$F$3);(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)))
5. AND(AND($GD3>$G$2);(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)))

Can anyone help me to simplify these conditional formatting? They are all successful when running singularly. I want to combine them because their format is all in pink. TIA.

Comment: Welcome! The question is not entirely clear - how exactly do you want to combine these expressions. Therefore, I can’t give an answer, but I can give a **hint**: the expression `AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5)` is repeated in each of the lines, therefore it makes sense to start by calculating this particular expression, if it is false, then and everything else is not necessary to calculate, right?`IF(AND($GE3>$B$4;$GE3<=$B$5),...,FALSE)` And checking if $GD3 is in range is easy: it must be at least `MAX($C$2:$G$2)` and at most `MIN($C$3:$F$3)` *What does $G$2 do here without $G$3 I don't understand*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Create a sample sheet showing what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine those expressions like this:

```
=or( 
  and($GD3 > $C$2; $GD3 <= $C$3; $GE3 > $B$4; $GE3 <= $B$5); 
  and($GD3 >= $D$2; $GD3 <= $D$3; $GE3 > $B$4; $GE3 <= $B$5); 
  and($GD3 >= $E$2; $GD3 <= $E$3; $GE3 > $B$4; $GE3 <= $B$5); 
  and($GD3 >= $F$2; $GD3 <= $F$3; $GE3 > $B$4; $GE3 <= $B$5); 
  and($GD3 > $G$2; $GE3 > $B$4; $GE3 <= $B$5) 
)
```

The formula can be simplified to:

```
=and( 
  $B$4 < $GE3; $GE3 <= $B$5; 
  or( 
    and($C$2 < $GD3; $GD3 <= $C$3); 
    and($D$2 <= $GD3; $GD3 <= $D$3); 
    and($E$2 <= $GD3; $GD3 <= $E$3); 
    and($F$2 <= $GD3; $GD3 <= $F$3); 
    $G$2 < $GD3
  ) 
)
```